# How to blit the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I render and cache chunks of an HTML DOM?

A classic technique in render heavy 2D games and other apps is to pre-render and cache intensive chunks of the UI. This is called [blitting](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/gamedev-glossary-what-is-blitting--gamedev-2247). I use it a lot in 2D games I build for fun.

In an actual work scenario, I would like to do this with native html DOM elements -- render them off screen, cache the results, and then insert the cached results into my displayed DOM. The key is that, once rendered, the result (whether in literal bitmap or native DOM object representation) is both immutable and cheap to display.

Immutable means adding the rendered content to the display DOM will not mutate it (such as by intrinsically applying new styles). A full solution would not have any assumptions or requirements for the containing document. I.e. you could blit a chunk of a completely different website and insert it with fidelity.

The immediate use I have for this is in presenting snippets of syntax-highlighted code in a web interface for an expressions engine. The display is a basic table which could be showing dozens of 'rules', each of which have a 'condition' expression and and 'action' expression.

For the actual rule editing I use the excellent [ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). This gives me beautiful, custom highlighting both for a custom scripting language and for multiple variants of SQL. But for the tabular display I don't want to include dozens of fully-featured IDE editor instances squeezed into little `td`s. I would like to use a single ace editor instance to render each expression, then cache and display the rendered results.

Here's what I would like to do:

```js
var editorElement = $('#snippetEditor')[0];
var aceEditor = ace.edit(editorElement);
// .. set various options on the aceEditor ..
$('#myTable td[data-snippet-language]').each(function (i, el) {
    var code = $(el).text();
    aceEditor.setValue(code);

    // Assuming blit returns native DOM. If it creates
    // a bitmap, then blit will turn it into a base64 img literal
    var rendered = blit(editorElement);
    $(el).html($(rendered).html());
});
```

Comment: what kind of html is it? would canvas do better?

Comment: @DanielA.White Straight HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Using a canvas is an option for performing the rendering and/or packaging the result, but it should not require any part of the hosting document to be nested inside a canvas--i.e. it should allow inserting into existing DOM

Comment: i mean what kinds of elements do you need to offload?

Comment: @DanielA.White Mostly stylized text, such as my immediate application of custom syntax highlighting. Static css styling isn't an option because of all the complex processing that goes in to evaluating the input text (that's what the ace library does). But I'm looking for a more general solution. What if for example I wanted to grab a chunk off a different website and display that?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I need to get the bitmap data of an ace editor instance too for use with the wrapper application.

Answer (score 0):

http://google.github.io/incremental-dom/#demos
These dudes made something pretty cool that looks like a decent DOM blitter.

Comment: How does it work? Please make your answer self-contained.